# Once-off run a program with command line options from shortcut

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments

Is there any program that will let me run a shortcut, but add additional arguments to the command line? Ideally, I would like this as an option in the right click menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Open++](http://dengdun.webs.com/en/openxx.htm) Can do that with hard links, but I haven't been able to get it working with short cuts.

You can right-click, choose "Run with parameters" and manually add your parameters, or you can customize your own entry with its own name, and its own parameters.